# awk substring with slash in string

Tags: awk, substring

I have a fastq file with biological sequences. Example, a file named `test.fq` with the following four lines:

```
@ABC012:106:087H3Y27J:1:11112:11679:1250 2:N:0:CGTAGCTC+ACGCTATA
CAGCATAGCTCTTAAACTGACATCAATTGATCATATCCGG
+
6FF/AFF/FAFF/FFF6FFFFF/AFFFAAFFAFFFF//FA
```

I want to extract 20 characters (including the slashes in the count) starting at the 18th position from every even numbered line.

I tried

```
awk 'FNR%2==0{s=$0; print substr($s,18,20); next} 1' test.fq
```

It works fine when there are no slashes in the strings, and also sometimes when there are slashes, but not for the above string. Can anyone please advise how to fix this? Also, why does the above awk statement work for some strings with slashes, e.g.. `FFAFFFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFF` but not others?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$s` which points to the field number using the `$`, but it should be just `s` instead.

```
awk 'FNR%2==0{s=$0; print substr(s,18,20); next} 1' test.fq
```

If the line should also start with a number:

```
awk 'FNR%2==0 && /^[0-9]/{print substr($1,18,20); next}1' test.fq
```

Note that if the checks are not passed, you will still print the whole line due to the `}1`

Comment: for line #4 of OP's sample input `s=$0=6FF/AF...`  which `awk` treats as `s=6` so `$s ==> $6` says to process the 6th (white space delimited) field which in this case doesn't exist (there's only the one white space delimited field) so the substring of nothing is nothing

Answer (score 0):

instead of checking for a `modulo %` being `0`, using `next`, and a tail print of `} 1`, flip the order of those instead :

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NR % 2 || $-_=substr($-_,18,20)'
```

|

```
@ABC012:106:087H3Y27J:1:11112:11679:1250 2:N:0:CGTAGCTC+ACGCTATA
TGACATCAATTGATCATATC
+
FFFFF/AFFFAAFFAFFFF/
```

- `NR % 2` does what the `} 1'` performs for odd numbered lines
- back-assigning the `substr()` into `$0` with no action block is same
  as `print + next`, just slightly less verbose.

if you're very concerned about slashes being misinterpreted as `regex`, then make it

```
mawk 'NR % 2 || ($_=substr($_,18,20))^_'
```

this way, nothing of the input string gets interpreted at all, since the `0-th power, i.e. 1`, at the tail of it is the boolean expression being evaluated, instead of the `regex`